# jquery open multiple overlay with different content

Tags: jquery

I do not come on. how do I open for each overlay the right content? currently he invites only the second container.

my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XNpN5/3/

```
 $('.open').click(
            function() {
                $('.overlay').show('slow',
                    function() {
                        $('.container').fadeIn('slow');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
         $('.close').click(
            function() {
                $('.container').hide('slow',
                     function() {
                          $('.overlay').fadeOut();          
                     }    
                );
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/XNpN5/7/

**JS:-**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('.open').click(function () {
         var clickedElement=this;
         $('.overlay').show('slow', function () {
             $(clickedElement).parent().find('.container').fadeIn('slow');

         });
     });
     $('.close').click(function () {
         $('.container').hide('slow', function () {
             $('.overlay').fadeOut();
         });
     });
 });
```

**HTML:-**

```
<ul class="row">
    <li> <a href="#" class="open">»Australien</a>

        <div class="container">
            <p> <a href="#" class="close">close</a>

            </p>
            <p class="changeText">Australien</p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#" class="open">»Australien2</a>

        <div class="container">
            <p> <a href="#" class="close">close</a>

            </p>
            <p class="changeText">Australien2</p>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate between the two. One way would be to use ids.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XNpN5/4/)

```
 $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#open1').click(
            function() {
                $('.overlay').show('slow',
                    function() {
                        $('#overlay1').fadeIn('slow');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
        $('#open2').click(
            function() {
                $('.overlay').show('slow',
                    function() {
                        $('#overlay2').fadeIn('slow');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
         $('.close').click(
            function() {
                $('.container').hide('slow',
                     function() {
                          $('.overlay').fadeOut();          
                     }    
                );
            }
        );  
    }
);
```

Comment: ok thx, but I have 20 links, the js will not be too big? you can not do that kind of dynamic?

Comment: @herrsaidy, yes. Abstract the common parts into a function, which is passed the variable parts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute, to make the difference about containers. like this:

html:

```
 <li> <a href="#" class="open" data-target='A1'>Australien</a></li>
 <div class="container A1">
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('.open').click(
            function() {
                var target=$(this).data('target');
                $('.overlay').show('slow',
                    function() {
                        $('.container.'+target).fadeIn('slow');

                    }
                );
            }
        );
         $('.close').click(
            function() {
                $(this).parents('.container').hide('slow',
                     function() {
                          $('.overlay').fadeOut();          
                     }    
                );
            }
        );  
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/XNpN5/5/

---

it also possible to calculate index of current link, but it not so clean to read.